# Check wheather a ftp busy or not?

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm using an `ftp` to read file and do some thing with them.

my question is how can i check if while I'm trying to accesses the `ftp`.someone else is writing some data to the same `directory`?

I want to be able to know if the directory in the ftp is currently "`busy`" or not.

I am using `C#` for my code.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve a different problem in the wrong place. What happens if you write a file to a directory while another user is "busy" in that directory? Is the problem maybe that you have two clients trying to write the same file? Anyway what you are looking for is not built into the FTP protocol, so a server cannot tell you who else is logged on and what they are doing.

Comment: What is wrong if the ftp server is busy? Why are you checking it?